# Issue drawing using graphics Java

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I am trying to draw an Oval with a for loop iterating through a list of coordinates that each contain an x value and y value. Currently, it does not seem to be drawing anything after I start the program. It draws the first time, but when I try drawing when the program is running, it doesn't seem to be drawing.

Here is the code for drawing:

```
private void render(){
    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    //Draw Here!

    DrawGrid(g);
    g.fillOval(100, 100, 10, 10);//this seems to draw
    for(int i = 0; i < points.size();i++){//this doesn't draw....
        System.out.println(points.get(i));
        g.drawString(points.get(i).toString(), points.get(i).x*100-5+100, points.get(i).y-5-300);
        g.fillOval(points.get(i).x*100-5+100, points.get(i).y-5-300, 10, 10);
    }
    //End Drawing!
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
```

If you need more details, I am using graphics from java.awt library. Also, I have done this in the past, but I don't know why it isn't working this time.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

**This part is your issue:**

```
points.get(i).x*100-5+100
```

Specifically `x*100`

You are drawing off screen. We can see this by breaking it down:
Lets assume that you have a point of x=28.

**Lets do the math on that:**

> For X = 28 you will have the following calc: (28 * 100) - (5 + 100) = 2695

That X point of `2695` looks very large to me. You would need a 4k screen or ultrawide screen to see it.

**The solution:**
Have a think about why you are using `x*100`, and reduce it so that the point fits on your screen. Also, if you have a small y point, then it will be in the negatives (Example: `15-5-300 = -290`), and will probably draw above your screen and out of sight.